# Grate on someone's ears / nerves

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, idioms, expressions, phrases

What does the sentence below mean?

> - His voice **grates on my ears**.
> - His voice **grates on my nerves**.

Please have a look on [Longman's definition](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/grate) below:

**[To grate on](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/grate)** (to annoy someone): 
 - Mr Fen had a loud voice that grated on her ears.

### My questions:

1. How shall I paraphrase them with a precise definition?
2. Do they indicate that his voice is "**annoying**" or so they imply that his voice is "**harsh sounding**" or something else?

Does the following sentence sound **informal** and disapproving to you? (There are some reason behind asking this question):

> - His voice is in one's nerves.